# Timeout raised too late using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`

Tags: python, multithreading

When running this code

```
def f(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    return t

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=300) as pool:
    res = list(pool.map(f, [2, 10], timeout=1))
```

it does throw a `TimeoutError`, but only after 10 seconds (the max of the `time.sleep`s). If would expect the `TimeoutError` to happen after 1 second (the timeout duration).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

with Pool(300) as pool:
    map_res = pool.map_async(f, [2, 10])
    res = map_res.get(timeout=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def f(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    return t

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=300)
res = list(pool.map(f, [2, 10], timeout=1))
```

it works but honestly I don't know why using context manager it doesn't work